# Is $[-\frac{1}{f(-x)},\frac{1}{f(x)}]$ bounded, when $f(x)$ is strictly positive?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The question arose as the text I was reading states, that for $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty,-\infty\}$, the image of which is strictly positive, than the space
$$\left[-\frac{1}{f(-\infty)},\frac{1}{f(\infty)}\right]$$
is bounded.

If this is so, why?

The only thing specified about $f$, is that it i strictly positive.

#### My process

Lets say $f(x)>0$ for all $x$. Therefore the range of $f$ "at most"
$$(0,\infty)$$

Now, the limit of the function 
$$\lim_{f(x)\to 0} \frac{1}{f(x)}=\infty$$
so, lets say $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$, how can the interval
$$\left[-\frac{1}{f(-\infty)},\frac{1}{f(\infty)}\right]$$
be bounded?

### Edit for clarification

[image]

The last sentence of this proof claims the space is bounded... Note that the lemma it mentions is just the finite version of this one.

Comment: Any interval $[a,b]$, where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, is bounded.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I added an image of the lemma, where my question arose. If you could please explain it to me in an answer, I would be grateful. It is the last line.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Sorry for the onslaught... I have added a clarified question, in response to your reply. I hope you caa help me.

Comment: It's as I said: $ a = -1/\delta(-\infty)$ and $b = 1/\delta(\infty)$ are real numbers, so $[a,b]$ is a bounded interval, and apparently Lemma 4.9.1 applies to bounded intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not so. Take $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: A big part of the proof I am reading relies on this statement... Which is why I asked, as it seemed that way to me too. I will edit the question and add an image on the lemma where they claim it to be. Please take a look, it is the last sentence in the proof. It really bothers me, as I had come to the same conclusion as you... If you think it not appropriate, please tell me, and I will accept your answer as is.

Comment: the first indented equation says $(-\infty,x) \subset (-\infty,-1/\delta(\infty))$, which leads me to believe that $-1/\delta(\infty)$ is bounded above by 0 and below by $x \in \mathbb{R}$. It seems you need to use some property of "$\delta$ fine", whatever that means.

Comment: So, your opinion is that the $-1/\delta(\infty)$ is bounded above by $0$ and below by $x$? This would make sense... Thank you! For completion -> There is no mentioning of any other properties of $\delta$. The "$\delta$ fine means that $A_i=(−\infty,x)\subset(−\infty,−1/\delta(\infty))$ in case of infinity, and $A_i=\subset (x_i-\delta(x_i),x_i+\delta(x_i))$ for the finite case